# How do I make a function that replaces Characters in a randomly generated 2D List?

Tags: python, list, function, variables

Title. Essentially I want to replace the characters that would be randomly generated in a 2d List I made. Here's an example, I'd like to replace 0 with 9

```
 0 0 0 0
 1 1 1 1 
 2 2 2 2 
 3 3 3 3 

9 9 9 9 
1 1 1 1 
2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3
```

But I am not entirley familiar with how I am supposed to do this because I am rather new at programming.

My first attempt was to make a function with a parameter that wiuld Identify and characters that had 0 and then make a seperate funtinon that would return it and replace it with 9, but it wouldn't even start it, and I have no idea where to go from there. Any help would be
appreciated.

code:

```
import random

SIZE = 4
EMPTY = " "
PERSON = "P"
PET = "T"
POOP = "O"
ERROR = "!"
CLEANED = "."
MAX_RANDOM = 10


def clean(world,endRow,endColumn):
    if world == POOP, POOP == CLEAN:
        
    print("Scooping the poop")


# @args(reference to a alist of characters,integer,integer)
# Function will count the number of occurences of the character specified by the user up the specified
# end point (row/column specified by the user).
# @return(character,integer)
def count(world,endRow,endColumn):
    print("Counting number of occurances of a character")
    number = 0
    element = input("Enter character: ")
    return(element,number)

# Randomly generates an 'occupant' for a location in the world
# @args(none)
# Randomly generates and returns a character according to the specified probabilities.
#  *50% probability empty space
#  *20% probability of a person
#  *10% probability of a pet
#  *20% probability of fecal matter
# @return(character)
def createElement():
    tempNum = random.randrange(MAX_RANDOM)+1

    # 50% chance empty
    if ((tempNum >= 1) and (tempNum <= 5)):
        tempElement = EMPTY

    # 20% of a person
    elif ((tempNum >= 6) and (tempNum <= 7)):
        tempElement = PERSON

    # 10% chance of pet
    elif (tempNum == 8):
        tempElement = PET

    # 20% chance of poop in that location (lots in this world)
    elif ((tempNum >= 9) and (tempNum <= 10)):
        tempElement = POOP

    # In case there's a bug in the random number generator
    else:
        tempElement = ERROR

    return(tempElement)

# Creates the SIZExSIZE world. Randomly populates it with the
# return values from function createElement
# @args(none)
# Randomly populates the 2D list which is returned to the caller.
# @return(reference to a list of characters)
def createWorld():
    world = [] #  Create a variable that refers to a 1D list.
    r = 0

    #  Outer 'r' loop traverses the rows.
    # Each iteration of the outer loop creates a new 1D list.
    while (r < SIZE):
        tempRow = []
        world.append(tempRow)  # Create new empty row
        c = 0
        # The inner 'c' loop traverses the columns of the newly
        # created 1D list creating and initializing each element
        # to the value returned by createElement()
        while (c < SIZE):
            element = createElement()
            tempRow.append(element)
            c = c + 1
        r = r + 1
    return(world)

# Shows the elements of the world. All the elements in a row will
# appear on the same line.
# @args(reference to a list of characters)
# Displays the 2D list with each row on a separate line.
# @return(nothing)
def display(world):
    print("OUR WORLD")
    print("========")
    r = 0
    while (r < SIZE): # Each iteration accesses a single row
        c = 0
        while (c < SIZE):  # Each iteration accesses an element in a row
            print(world[r][c], end="")
            c = c + 1
        print()  # Done displaying row, move output to the next line
        r = r + 1


# @args(none)
# @return(integer,integer)
def getEndPoint():
    #Declaring local variables
    endRow = -1
    endColumn = -1

    return(endRow,endColumn)


# Starting execution point for the program.
def start():
    world = createWorld()
    display(world)
    endRow,endColumn = getEndPoint()
    element,number = count(world,endRow,endColumn)
    print("# occurances of %s=%d" %(element,number))
    clean(world,endRow,endColumn)
    display(world)

start()
```

Comment: Can you include the code you have tried along with the error message?

Comment: Done. Just edited it in.